# creating a edgelist from a dataframe

Tags: r, edges, sna

I am trying to get from this:

```
session location sequence weight INDIVIDUAL action
a1      texas    1        10       john       Z1
a1      texas    2        5        peter      Z2
a1      texas    3        3        ben        Z1
a1      texas    4        5        peter      Z5
a2      calif    1        25       esther     Z3
a2      calif    2        5        peggy      Z2
a2      calif    3        10       greg       Z5
```

to this:

```
INDIVIDUAL1 INDIVIDUAL2 weight
john        peter       10
john        ben         10
peter       john        5
peter       ben         5
ben         john        3
ben         peter       3
peter       john        5
peter       ben         5
```

I am exploring a number of options, including the use of for-loops, but I am a little concern that it may take too long as my dataset gets really big. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain your logic? Why does `john peter` have weight 10 but `peter john` have weight 5? Do the `sequence` or `action` columns have any relevance? Is `session` equivalent to `location`? If not which one matters?

Comment: No clue how you are getting from the input data set to your output dataset.  Can you explain your logic? What exactly are you *trying* to do?  -- Also, what *code* have you tried?  --  Welcome to SO. Please review: [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*, and usually you will need to include a **[Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications. The input data is communication utterances recorded in sequence. E.g., in session a1 sequence 1, john utters for 10 minutes and the utterance was directed at peter and ben. in session a1 sequence 2, peter utters for 5 minutes, directing the communication to john and peter. The edgelist is just for session a1. Hope this make sense?

Comment: To create an adjacency matrix and then an edgelist, you have to explain which is the event that creates the connection between the individuals.
I don't understand how you get that edgelist from your dataframe...

Comment: @gregor sharp eyes. That was a typo on my end - I've corrected the typo. Sequence matters because I am tracking communication over time. Session and location are not the same for my inquiry as the same location can have multiple sessions.

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo hope my clarification provided a better context.

Comment: Not at all, I don't understand which variable records the utterance action (and direction).

Comment: I mean, I get that `sequence` matters for *something*, but for the problem at hand, *creating an edgelist*, which columns matter? It seems like you are saying the `session`, `individual`, and `weight` are the only meaningful inputs for the output edgelist. Andy `individual`s with the same `session` are considered adjacent, and the `weight` corresponding to `INDIVIDUAL1` is to be preserved. Is this correct?

Comment: Or do you want to make sure that the edgelist is ordered by `sequence`, meaning only `location` and `action` are irrelevant for the edgelist generation?

Comment: @gregor yes, you are right. thanks for separating wheat from chaff regarding the columns. yes, it is important that the resultant edgelist is ordered by correct sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach with a self-join. I'll leave the dropping of the `sequence` and `session` columns to you.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(session, weight, sequence, INDIVIDUAL) %>%
  inner_join(., select(., session, INDIVIDUAL), by = "session") %>%
  rename(INDIVIDUAL1 = INDIVIDUAL.x, INDIVIDUAL2 = INDIVIDUAL.y) %>%
  filter(INDIVIDUAL1 != INDIVIDUAL2) %>%
  unique %>%
  arrange(session, sequence)
#    session weight sequence INDIVIDUAL1 INDIVIDUAL2
# 1       a1     10        1        john       peter
# 2       a1     10        1        john         ben
# 3       a1      5        2       peter        john
# 4       a1      5        2       peter         ben
# 5       a1      3        3         ben        john
# 6       a1      3        3         ben       peter
# 7       a1      5        4       peter        john
# 8       a1      5        4       peter         ben
# 9       a2     25        1      esther       peggy
# 10      a2     25        1      esther        greg
# 11      a2      5        2       peggy      esther
# 12      a2      5        2       peggy        greg
# 13      a2     10        3        greg      esther
# 14      a2     10        3        greg       peggy
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Gregor. I have this error message "Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"" What do you think is happening?

Comment: I think I called the data `df` (since you didn't specify) but you called it something else and you need to update my code with the actual name of your data frame.

Comment: You are right. And this certainty sorted out for me. Grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="session location sequence weight INDIVIDUAL action
a1      texas    1        10       john       Z1
a1      texas    2        5        peter      Z2
a1      texas    3        3        ben        Z1
a1      texas    4        5        peter      Z5
a2      calif    1        25       esther     Z3
a2      calif    2        5        peggy      Z2
a2      calif    3        10       greg       Z5", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
ans <- df %>%
        group_by(session, location) %>%
        nest(INDIVIDUAL, weight) %>%
        mutate(data = map(data, ~cbind(expand.grid(.x$INDIVIDUAL, .x$INDIVIDUAL), expand.grid(.x$weight, .x$weight)) %>% setNames(paste0("V", 1:4)) )) %>%
        unnest() %>%
        filter(V1 != V2) %>%
        select(-V4) %>%
        arrange(session, V1)

# A tibble: 16 x 5
   # session location     V1     V2    V3
     # <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <int>
 # 1      a1    texas    ben   john     3
 # 2      a1    texas    ben  peter     3
 # 3      a1    texas    ben  peter     3
 # 4      a1    texas   john  peter    10
 # 5      a1    texas   john    ben    10
 # 6      a1    texas   john  peter    10
 # 7      a1    texas  peter   john     5
 # 8      a1    texas  peter   john     5
 # 9      a1    texas  peter    ben     5
# 10      a1    texas  peter    ben     5
# 11      a2    calif esther  peggy    25
# 12      a2    calif esther   greg    25
# 13      a2    calif   greg esther    10
# 14      a2    calif   greg  peggy    10
# 15      a2    calif  peggy esther     5
# 16      a2    calif  peggy   greg     5
```